# Callback function in sqlite3_exec (C API)

Tags: c, sqlite

When using the SELECT operation, if there are no results the callback function do not show results in the screen. I am trying to get a way to know, previously, if there are no results. For example, using the SELECT operation I would like to create a IF that will be true when there are no results in the table.
Sorry for the bad English.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h> 

static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
    int i;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", (const char*)data);
    for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
        printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    char *sql;
    const char* data = "Callback function called";

    rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
    if( rc ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        exit(0);
    }else{
        fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
    }

    sprintf (sql, "SELECT * from TABLE WHERE ADMIN LIKE ('%s%') AND PASSWORD LIKE ('%s%');", admin, password);

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);

    if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }else{
        fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a finer grain control over result fetching, than do not use `sqlite3_exec` - use a lower level API instead, to the tune:

```
sqlite3_prepare(...);
do {
    sqlite3_step();
    ....
} while (something);
sqlite3_finalize(...);
```

That's what `sqlite3_exec` does anyway. `sqlite3_step` will allow you to detect that no rows were returned and you can do your processing within the loop directly, without the need for callback.